# Scalar multiples of Frobenius norm and maximum column sum matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\lVert A\rVert_{1} $ denote the maximum column sum matrix norm, i.e. $max_{1\le j \le n} \sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}|$ and let $\lVert A\rVert_{2}$ denote the Frobenius norm defined on n-by-n complex matrices. Show that neither $c\lVert A\rVert_{1} $ nor $c\lVert A\rVert_{2} $ is a matrix norm for any $c \lt 1$.

For any $c \le 0$ it clearly doesn't satisfy the positivity or nonnegativity condition of a matrix norm so it's enough to consider $0 \lt c \lt 1$. My guess is that they both don't satisfy submultiplicativity since $c^2 \lt c$. But I just can't prove this fact. How can I show this part or is there any other condition that these norms don't satisfy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to prove that fact: let 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&\cdots\\0&0\\\vdots&&\ddots}
$$
Since $A^2 = A$, any (submultiplicative) matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ should satisfy $\|A\|^2 \leq \|A\|$. Neither of the modified norms can satisfy this for $c < 1$.